# How to return instead of print

Tags: python-3.x, calling-convention

I get the desired result from using `print()` but I want the same result when using a `return`. How can I change this to a `return`? When I do it only returns the first `key, value` where I want to have the four that are in the BST.

```
 def inOrder(self, aNode):
       if aNode:
        self.inOrder (aNode.leftChild)
        print (aNode.key + ' ' + aNode.payload +'\n')
        self.inOrder (aNode.rightChild)
```

The result I am looking for is to have four keys followed by their value.

Answer (score 5):

To do exactly what you want, you need to use the [yield](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) keyword (details for the `yield from` statement [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions))

```
 def inOrder(self, aNode):
       if aNode:
        yield from self.inOrder(aNode.leftChild)
        yield (aNode.key, aNode.payload)
        yield from self.inOrder(aNode.rightChild)
```

Which will return a generator, you can "expand" it by using `list(inOrder(...))`

You could also have a dedicated argument that you would update as you go through:

```
 def inOrder(self, aNode, res=[]):
       if aNode:
        self.inOrder(aNode.leftChild, res)
        res.append((aNode.key, aNode.payload))
        self.inOrder(aNode.rightChild, res)
```

Which will provide similar results.

Comment: You could also make `print` an argument, which you could use to pass something like `list.append` :)

Comment: Oh yeah that's clever, but for the case of retrieving a list of results you'd have to create the list separately and then pass its method to the function or you'd lose its reference. i.e `l = []; node.inOrder(node, l.append)`. It makes things a bit harder to read IMO.

Comment: so how would I return it as a string between each key followed by its value? thanks guys :)

Comment: For python 3.6 and above replace `(aNode.key, aNode.payload)` with `f"{aNode.key} {aNode.payload}"` or `" ".join((aNode.key, aNode.payload))` (which may require a cast to string).